# Laravel Sort Results by Query and URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want sort my Search Results with an URL. I cant use Controller in my way because i use Route for `/search`.

My Search Route:

```
Route::get ( '/', function () {
    $mydb= Product::paginate(200);
    return view ( 'search' )->withProduct($mydb);
} );

    Route::any ( '/search', function () {
        $q = Input::get ( 'q' );

        $sort = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(20);


        if($q != ""){
        $products = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->paginate (200)->setPath ( '' );
        $pagination = $products->appends ( array (
                    'q' => Input::get ( 'q' ) 
            ) );




        if (count ( $products ) > 0)
            return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products )->withQuery ( $q );
        }
```

Now i want create an Button where i can Sort the results from `query` search.

Button Example:

```
<a href="/search?q={{ $query }}">Sort by Price</a>
```

I want add like this to my Route:

```
$sort = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(20);
```

This dont work..
And then add the `{{ $sort }}`behind my Button URL like:

```
<a href="/search?q={{ $query }}&`{{ $sort }}">Sort by Price</a>
```

Any Idea how i can do it correct? Sorry i am an Beginner with Laravel and i know its not correct.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to define a new route with a parameter. Something like

`Route::any('/search/{{query}}', function ($query){
 ..your logic here

});`

Comment: Thanks, you mean with "..your logic here" my "$sort = Product::where..."?

Comment: Yeah,do your sort inside there and pass the sorted `$products` to the view.
You can also add another route with second parameter:

`Route::any('/search/{{query}}/{{sort}}', function ($query, $sort) {...});`

Comment: Great, and how can i use this in Button?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a lot of errors in your code. 
But this line

`` <a href="/search?q={{ $query }}&`{{ $sort }}">Sort by Price</a> ``

could be

`<a href="/search?q={{ $query }}&orderby=price">Sort by Price</a>`

Then in your closure

```
$q = Input::get ( 'q' );

$orderby = Input::has('orderby') ? Input::get('orderby') : 'created_at';

$sort = Product::where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orderBy($orderby,'desc')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Then i get the error: "Undefined variable: sort " in my Blade :/ WHy i get this Error, its defined in route?

Comment: You provided the $sort variable so I assumed it was set, I have updated my answer with a possible solution by hard coding the value. Otherwise you might need to fix some errors and be a bit more specific.

Comment: Must i change the "'created_at';" in route also to "price" from Button?

Comment: Okay it works now but without any Results if i click the button, just go to URL from Button but dont sort the Products.

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete route?

Comment: i have changed the "$sort" from the same line that works "    if($q != ""){
    $products =" I think its correct

Comment: Your code is not complete so I can't see where the issue is

Comment: Updated the first line. Thats all

Comment: What about the search route, that is not complete

Comment: The search Function works fine. "$sort" name can be changed but with the "$sort" line i have defined sort if i am correct?

Comment: Yes, but blade will not know about it unless you send it to the view. eg. ```return view ( 'search' )->with('sort', $sort);```

Comment: Okay i understand, but i must change the line on the end from my code like: "if (count ( $products ) > 0)
        return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $products ,$sort )->withQuery ( $q );
    }" ?